# Material table: where to put dataSource initialization to preserve component state with router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components, router-outlet, material-table

I am using Angular 8 and material data table with different filters as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51515695/filtering-different-columns-in-a-material-table/51683898#51683898) 
This is placed inside a component to which I navigate through router-outlet with one minor difference, I initialize the dataSource in ngAfterViewInit and assign data from API to this.dataSource.data at the end of the block to achieve fastest performance as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283659/angular-6-mattable-performance-in-1000-rows)

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (record, filter: any) => {
      let result = true;
      let keys = Object.keys(record); // keys of the object data 
      for (const key of keys) {
        let searchCondition = filter.conditions[key]; // get search filter method
        if (searchCondition && searchCondition !== 'none') {
          if (filter.methods[searchCondition](record[key], filter.values[key]) === false) { // invoke search filter 
            result = false // if one of the filters method not succeed the row will be remove from the filter result 
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      return result
    };
    this.apiService.getLogsNested().subscribe(logsFromApi => {
      this.dataSource.data = logsFromApi;
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
    });
    console.log('logs ngAfterViewInit');
  }
```

The issue is that when I filter something in the component with data table and then switch between different routes/components each time I go back to my component with data table I don't see the filtered results as it is getting re-initialized when switching between routes. I confirmed ngAfterViewInit is getting called in such event. 
Can I somehow preserve the state of component dataTable when switching between the routes ?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the solution with RouteReuseStrategy from accepted answer in stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280471/how-to-implement-routereusestrategy-shoulddetach-for-specific-routes-in-angular)
It solved my issue.