# angular 2+, mat table - filtering not working for model in model

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material, filtering, mat-table

I have mat-table with dataSource that models looks like this:

.ts

```
interface DataModel {
  id: number;
  projectName: string;
  material: material;
}

interface material {
  materialID: number;
  materialName: string;
}
```

.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="" #input>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

   
    <ng-container matColumnDef="projectName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> projectName</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.projectName}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="material">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> material </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.material ? row.material.materialName  : ''  }} </td>
    </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

 
    <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
      <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

1. Filtering from the mat table does not work for material cell.
2. The last line of tr, which should show the message if there is no match, doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Edit.:
Angular ver.: 8.0
Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxmmdz?file=src/app/table-filtering-example.ts   -  filtering not working for {{row.color.name}}

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? The *matNoDataRow was added in angular v10, so it might be unavailable in your project. Concerning the filtering - it's hard to say without seeing your code responsible for filtering :) It's a good practice to reproduce your issue on stackblitz and link it in the question - it ensures more people will take their time to look at the question, as it takes them less time.

Comment: Can you please create a StackBlitz example.

Comment: If you want to filter some complex data model, you can create custom `filterPredicate` method and write your logic to filter data. Check this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51515695/filtering-different-columns-in-a-material-table?rq=1)

Comment: @TotallyNewb Angular 8.0, but filtering works fine for id and project name :/

Comment: Hope this helps:https://therichpost.com/angular-material-table-with-custom-filter-working-tutorial/

Comment: @AmitVishwakarma https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxmmdz?file=src/app/table-filtering-example.ts filtering colors not working because I have {{color.name}} instead {{color}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found simply solution.

```
export interface UserData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  color: string;
}
export interface ColorName {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
const ELEMENT_DATA_COLOR: ColorName[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'red'},
  {id: 2, name: 'orange'}
];
const ELEMENT_DATA: UserData[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'one',color:ELEMENT_DATA_COLOR[0].name },
  {id: 2, name: 'two',color: ELEMENT_DATA_COLOR[1].name}
];
```

But I have one question. I get data from .net core API. and it looks like:

```
   const ELEMENT_DATA: UserData[] = [
      {id: 1, name: 'one',color:ELEMENT_DATA_COLOR[0] },
      {id: 2, name: 'two',color: ELEMENT_DATA_COLOR[1]}
    ];
```

so if I want filtering works I need to save data to another model where color is string not object Color because filtering not working for {{row.color.name}} (using for ex. AutoMapper) ?